# How to add additional domain name for the certificate which is already generated in ACM

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have generated a certificate for ELB (both private & public) to AWS ACM and done with Import.

Is there any way to add an additional domain name to the existing ACM cert.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, you will add to recreate it…

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-bestpractices.html